# How to use properly deaccent method from gensim?

Tags: python, string, gensim

My goal is to read the lines inside a file and to replace all special characters like french characters (à, é, ç, ...) by normal characters (a, e, c, ...)

I work with Python 3 and in the documentation of gensim, the example works with a simple sentence like : deaccent("àéç) but not with lines I read from a file
At this time, I just get "àéç" and not "aec" with my code

```
from gensim.utils import deaccent

def getTextFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        text = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]
    file.close()
    for line in text:
        print(deaccent(line))
    return text
```

My file contains : àéç

I would like to get : aec

Comment: Use `str.replace()` https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: @DrBwts I have always the same problem with : print(line.replace(line, deaccent(line)))

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it works fine:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 20:50:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
In [1]: from gensim.utils import deaccent
In [2]: deaccent('àéç')
Out[2]: 'aec'
In [3]: astr = 'àéç'
In [4]: dstr = deaccent(astr)
In [5]: print(dstr)
aec
```

If you want your `getTextFromFile()` method to return de-accented text, don't return the original `text`, but the results of the `deaccent()` call

Comment: I found where does the problem come. It was due to the : with open() in which I didn't include : encoding=utf-8. Thank you for your answer.